# Can _lodash test an array to check if an array element has a field with a certain value?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a variable `selectedSubTopicId` and I have an array of subTopic objects: `objectiveDetail.subTopics[]`.  Each `subTopic` **object** has a **field** `subTopicId`

I would like to use this to enable or disable and Add topic button. Can I use lodash in the ng-disabled to test this array and report true if any `subTopic` object element of the array has a `subTopicId` that is equal to the `selectedSubTopicId`.

Here's a sample of the data that's in objectiveDetail. In this case there's just one element in the subTopics array.

```
{"objectiveDetailId":285,
 "objectiveId":29,
 "number":1,
 "text":"x",
 "subTopics":[{"subTopicId":1,
               "number":1}]
}
```

Here is the code in my Angular Controller suggested by thefourtheye:

```
    $scope.checkDuplicateSubTopicId = function (objectiveDetail, sSubTopic) {
        if (_.some(objectiveDetail.subTopics, function(currentTopic) {
            return _.contains(currentTopic, selectedSubTopicId);
        })) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My button with the click function not shown looks like this:

```
   <button data-ng-disabled="checkDuplicateSubTopicId(objectiveDetail, subTopicId)">
       Add Topic
   </button>
```

The problem is that it's not quite working and the button does not show disabled.

Comment: Yes you can (hint: http://lodash.com/docs#some).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

<sub>You didn't ask for how to do it, but I assume that's what you wanted to know.</sub>

As I already mentioned, you can use [`_.some`](http://lodash.com/docs#some), which will iterate over every element in the array and execute a callback. In that callback you can test whether the value of the topic's property equals the value of the variable:

```
var result = _.some(objectiveDetail.subTopics, function (topic) {
  return topic.subTopicId === selectedSubTopicId;
});
```

`_.some` will skip the remaining elements if it found one for which the callback returned `true`.

Comment: Thanks! This should be aliased to `_.includes` or `_.exists`.

Answer (score 20):

There is also a bit more elegant form:

```
var result = _.some(objectiveDetail.subTopics, {subTopicId: selectedSubTopicId});
```

Comment: If the value is not nested you can't use shorthand.
_.some(['a','b','c'], _.partial(_.eq, 'd'))

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`_.some`](http://lodash.com/docs#some) method, like this

```
var _ = require("lodash");

var objectiveDetail = {"objectiveDetailId":285,
 "objectiveId":29,
 "number":1,
 "text":"x",
 "subTopics":[{"subTopicId":1,
               "number":1}]
};

var selectedSubTopicId = 1;

if (_.some(objectiveDetail.subTopics, function(currentTopic) {
    return currentTopic.subTopicId === selectedSubTopicId;
})) {
    console.log("selectedSubTopicId exists");
}
```

**Output**

```
selectedSubTopicId exists
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me very well: It helps where you have many columns of data to check against, say title, category and description.

To check if `stringTosearch` is found in any of those columns of data, you can do:

```
let searchResults = _.filter(yourArrayHere, (item) => {
            return item.title.indexOf(stringTosearch) > -1
                    || item.category.indexOf(stringTosearch) > -1
                    || item.description.indexOf(stringTosearch) > -1;
        });
```

It will return any object of your array that has `stringTosearch` in any of the columns you specified.