# When I define an object in an object in Javascript is there a way I can do this one time?

Tags: javascript

My code looks like this:

```
        $scope.modal = {};
        $scope.modal.option = {};
```

Could I combine these into just one statement or do I always have to do this in two stages?

Comment: $scope.modal = {"option" : {}};

Comment: Why didn't you try something very similar to what you've already shown in previous questions, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281286/can-i-use-lodash-to-remove-an-element-from-an-array ...or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278661/can-lodash-test-an-array-to-check-if-an-array-element-has-a-field-with-a-certai ...or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954718/how-can-i-pass-some-string-containing-index-into-my-directive ...You've obviously declared an object in an object several times already. So what's the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$scope.modal = { option: {} };
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.modal = {
  option : {  },
  anotherOption : 12
}